# Cakephp doesn't read browser cookie

Tags: php, cakephp, cookies, cakephp-1.3

It is tricky for me since I'm a newbie to cakephp.

So, the problem:

I have a cookie called "userClick" which I store through jQuery. But I need to read it in some cases in cakephp. The problem now is that cakephp doesn't recognize it.

If I use $_COOKIE it works fine but with `var_dump( $this->Cookie->read('userClick'))` I get an empty array, is there something to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding 'Cookie' to your components (in the controller class, a parameter should be named components):

```
var $components = array('Cookie');
```

See here: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Components/Cookies.html